# AWS CLI: get RDS free space

Tags: aws-cli

How to get free space of RDS instance using aws-cli?

Tried:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances | grep -i 'size|space|free|available|used'
```

but no result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
STARTTIME="$(date -u -d '5 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%dT%T')"
ENDTIME="$(date -u '+%Y-%m-%dT%T')"
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/RDS \
--metric-name FreeStorageSpace\
--start-time $STARTTIME --end-time $ENDTIME --period 300 \
--statistics Average\
--dimensions="Name=DBInstanceIdentifier, Value=<DB_INSTANCE>"
```

otput sample:

```
{
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2016-02-11T08:50:00Z", 
            "Average": 45698627515.73333, 
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        }
    ], 
    "Label": "FreeStorageSpace"
}
```